# how to take backup of two tables in the mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I am aware of mysqldump utility, as it takes backup of entire database. I need to take backup of two tables in mysql database, in which one table with all entries and second one without entries. and also i need both tables in a single sql(i.e mydb.sql) file.

is it possible ?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to take backup of `table1` as `table1Backup`? but what did you mean by the `second one without entries` ?

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu , it means , i need table1 without it's data and table2 with it's data(rows)

Comment: @rhavendc can you please explain how

Comment: @GirishKumar Look at @ ax. answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysqldump.html) can also dump single tables, optionally with or without data:

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]

--no-data, -d: Do not write any table row information (that is, do not dump table contents).
```

So to dump table1 with all entries, and table2 without entries, you would invoke mysqldump twice like this:

```
mysqldump db_name table1 > table1.sql
mysqldump --no-data db_name table2 > table2.sql
```

**UPDATE**: To dump both tables into a single file, you can append the output of the second command to the first:

```
mysqldump db_name table1 > dump.sql
mysqldump --no-data db_name table2 >> dump.sql
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need both table in a single .sql file

Comment: Then just append the output of the second command to the first. I'll update my answer.